# Is window.open() still useful nowadays?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and stumbled across the `window.open()` function. When I tested it out, it seems that major browsers like Chrome block the popup window. To me, the major function of `open()` is no longer useful anymore. So does this function still have any usage in current practice?

Comment: It's very useful, it's the only way to just open a blank window, but the user has to instanciate it by clicking something etc. otherwise it's what's called an *"annoying popup"*, and most browsers try to block those.

Comment: As @sg.cc answered, chrome makes a lot of distinctions for actions if they're initiated by a user interaction event (see how it behaves with fullscreen requests). window.open is generally fine if you're using it properly, but `<a target="_new"...` may be preferable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think Chrome only blocks `window.open` if it is not preceded by a user action. For example, if you have an element whose `onclick` attribute is mapped to a function...

```
function clickedButton() {
  window.open(...);
}
```

This would work. While this....

```
function clickedButton(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.open(...);
  })
}
```

would not.

So yes, it is still useful if you are able to set up your application in such a way that popups are only opened in response to a user action.

While it's true that generally opening new windows is a bad idea for reasons mentioned by Jonathan.Brink, I have used them before for authentication. Logging in through Facebook, for example, requires a new tab or a new window to be opened with their URL (iframes don't work). When it hits my website in its callback again, I close the window, and update the (responsive) website with new login information. Closing new tabs feels.... weird.

Answer (score 4):

For some internal applications it may be useful, but [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Usability_issues) recommend against it:

> Generally speaking, it is preferable to avoid resorting to
>   window.open() for several reasons

Here are a few reasons why:

- tab browsing is usually preferred to opening new windows
- may not play nice with extensions/plugins
- heavy on system resources

Comment: That quote really isn't all that useful... Why not include why they recommend against it?

Comment: @Bern The quote may not be useful (without the full context found at the link), but a link to a very reputable source that explicitly recommends avoiding window.open() is

Comment: Then why include the quote in the first place?

Comment: @Bern because it is a very succinct way of summarizing the link I posted...in the article writer(s) own words

Comment: Doesn't saying "the Mozilla docs recommend against it" do that already? It's a good answer, but if you went to the effort of quoting the article anyway, why not include some of their reasoning too? Then the rest of us can be lazy. (For the record, the down-vote was not me)